# SwiftUI crash: "SheetBridge: abandoned presentation detected" when dismiss a sheet view (which is triggered by another sheet view )

Tags: ios, swiftui

Xcode 12 beta 4

I have this ContentView with two different modal views. I want to use `sheet(isPresented: onDismiss: content:)` to show first view, when it dismissed, automatically show the second view.

#### This is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showFirst = false
    @State var showSecond = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("showFirst: \(showFirst.description)")
            Text("showSecond: \(showSecond.description)")

            Button("show") {
                showFirst.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showFirst) {
                showSecond.toggle()
            } content: {
                FirstView(isPresented: $showFirst)
            }

            Text("")
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSecond) {
                    SecondView(isPresented: $showSecond)
                }

        }

    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("close") {
                isPresented = false
            }
            Text("First View")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("close") {
                isPresented = false
            }
            Text("Second View")
        }
    }
}
```

Then I run the code.
If I dismiss the model views by drag down gesture, it works.
If I dismiss the first view by taping the close button, it crashed when dismiss the second view, and throw a fatal error:

> Fatal error: SheetBridge: abandoned presentation detected: file SwiftUI, line 0

#### My confuse

It looks like when tap the first view's close button and dismiss the second view in any case, `$showSecond` didn't change to false.

Is there any difference between drag down and manualy toggle $isPresented?

And If I use `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` instead of binding `isPredented`, it crashed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update: retested - fixed in iOS15

The fix is to show second sheet with a bit delay, to give possibility for first sheet to finish completely.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
Button("show") {
    showFirst.toggle()
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showFirst) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {    // << here !!
        showSecond.toggle()
    }
} content: {
    FirstView(isPresented: $showFirst)
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a workaround for what really is a bug? I feel that SwiftUI should be able to handle this situation more gracefully...

Comment: it's working fine but some time getting crashed with same error  "Fatal error: SheetBridge: abandoned presentation detected: file SwiftUI, line 0"

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in Xcode 12 beta.

It's already fixed in the release version, tested in Xcode 12.2.

Comment: I still have it in Xcode 13 RC